# How to generate valid BTC address to withdraw coins to

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, address-generation, address-format

I set up bitcoind, and the complete blockchain is synced. I created a wallet, and I loaded the wallet.

How can I generate an address to deposit BTC to? I tried `bitcoin-cli getnewaddress` and I get this address `bc1q4mglxdp28f693lw476fnmcesq25tmfkcsfqnpk`, but at the Huobi exchange when I try to withdraw 0.001 BTC to that address as a test, I get the message "Invalid address."

What am I doing wrong? How can I create a valid BTC address on my loaded wallet to send BTC to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bitcoin client is generating a [P2WPKH (bech32 encoded) address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/66428/what-is-the-size-of-different-bitcoin-transaction-types), which is a newer address format [which has some benefits compared to legacy formats](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/78930/benefits-of-bech32-addresses). The address is valid, but for whatever reason, the exchange mentioned has not upgraded it's code to recognize and send to this address type yet.

The fix is easy: you just need to tell bitcoin-core to generate a legacy address. You can use the following command:

`$ bitcoin-cli getnewaddress "(address_label)" "legacy"`

You can substitute your own label in for the (address_label), this is just for local book-keeping purposes, it can also just be left blank if you'd like:

`$ bitcoin-cli getnewaddress "" "legacy"`